# which algorithm does T::Hashing::hash_of() uses?

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

I have used a storage map on the backend with a key of type T::Hash but now if I want to query the storage I need the specific key. I can create the key by using a hash function but I don't know which algorithm is being used in the T::Hashing::hash_of() function.

Comment: `T::Hashing` is probably the hashing configuration of your pallet? Could you please share the source code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`T::Hash` and `T::Hashing` are abstract types defined in FRAME System.

This allows the runtime developer to configure which hashing algorithm they would like to use.

So to answer to your question, you need to look at the configuration of these types in your runtime.

For a default Substrate chain (including Polkadot and probably most Parachains), this is configured to:

```rust
/// A hash of some data used by the chain.
pub type Hash = sp_core::H256;
```

```rust
impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    // -- snip --
    type Hash = Hash;
    type Hashing = BlakeTwo256;
    // -- snip --
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you don't (or should not) care. If you can get hold of a `T: Config` then you can use the
`T::Hasher::hash(slice)` ( which implements the [Hasher](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_core/trait.Hasher.html) trait ) to hash data that you'd like hashed in a similar fashion.